# Knight's tour algorithm using recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, knights-tour

I have been writing code to solve Knight's tour problem. I wrote this code and i am little confused now. I read and analyze it all over again,several times and was not able to find an error that causes the problem. I will appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>
const int N = 5; // size of table
int moves_table[2][8] = { { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -1, -1 }, { -2, -1, 1, 2, -1, -2, -2, -1 } }; //my moves table that i use to increment or decrement my x and y cordinates
int THETABLE[N][N] = { 0 }; //all elements of table equal to zero
bool iknight_tour(int x, int y, int r); // this function will return true if Knight is able to be on every place on chessmate, without being twice at the same place, starting from TABLE[x][y]
bool if_move_correct(int x, int y); //checks if move can be done
int main()
{
    bool some_variable = iknight_tour(0, 0, 1); 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            std::cout << THETABLE[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << some_variable;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
bool if_move_correct(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < N && x >= 0 && y < N && y >= 0 && THETABLE[x][y] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
bool iknight_tour(int x, int y, int r)
{
    THETABLE[x][y] = r;
    if (r == N*N)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            {
                if ((if_move_correct(x + moves_table[0][i], y + moves_table[1][i]))==true)
                {
                    if((iknight_tour(x + moves_table[0][i], y + moves_table[1][i], r + 1))==true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        THETABLE[x][y] = 0;
    }   
    return false;
}
```

For example for i_kinghtour(0,0,1) i got :
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

And i should get:
1 20 17 12 3
16 11 2 7 18
21 24 19 4 13
10 15 6 23 8
25 22 9 14 5

Comment: It might be helpful to state the problem

Comment: What problem do you have? [sscce!](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The problem is that i can not find the problem and this algorith is not working correctly.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski _what_ problem? The problem so far is you're claiming there's a problem but you're not explaining what makes you think so. Be specific, not vague, unless you want an equally vague answer such as "the problem is in the code".

Comment: What a coincidence. We didn't find the problem either. Oh, you mean *in your code*? Whats seems to be the problem in your code, then, and note: "It doesn't work" is *not* a problem; its an outcome (albeit an undesirable one). What are you *expecting*? What are you actually *getting*?

Comment: I mean, for example i run i_knighttour(0,0,0) and i got all elements equal to zero, and i can not find the error. My program should find the route for the knight and write some number to to the places where knight was.

Comment: What's the `r` parameter in the `i_knighttour` function?

Comment: How have you tested your functions?

Comment: @JoséTomásTocino `r` is the number that shows which move was made. for example: r=4 i takes four moves to get there.

Comment: @AlanStokes I tested move_correct and it works fine. The problem is in i_knightout function, and i suppose it is a problem with : 'THETABLE[x][y] = 0;' after the loop. Without this, program numerate every step but some values repeat themseleves and return false which is wrong output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This moves table:

```
int moves_table[2][8] = { { 1,  2,  2, 1, -1, -2, -1, -1 }, 
                          { -2, -1, 1, 2, -1, -2, -2, -1 } };
```

looks very odd.  You have -1,-1 appearing twice, and -2,-2.

Perhaps it would work better with:

```
int moves_table[2][8] = { { 1,  2,  2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 }, 
                          { -2, -1, 1, 2, -2, -1,  1,  2 } };
```